# Properly update restart GUI from another thread PyQT

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, user-interface, pyqt4

So i have an process which has its own thread and writes(appends) to an output.txt. Also i have a GUI which reads from this output.txt. I want to update the GUI whenever there is new content in the Output.txt. 
right now i do this by quiting and re-exec() the GUI. This works but looks awfull.

```
class _do_scan(QtCore.QThread):
    trigger = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.do_scan()  

    def do_scan():
        #when found smth and written to output.txt
        self.trigger.emit()

def main(options = None):

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    scan_thread = _do_scan()
    scan_thread.start()  

    scan_thread.trigger.connect(lambda: app.quit())

    while scan_thread.isRunning():
        window = Window()
        window.show()   
        app.exec_()

    window = Window()
    window.show()   
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any idea how i can manage it better?
i tried to use

```
    scan_thread.trigger.connect(lambda: window.update())
    scan_thread.trigger.connect(lambda: window.repaint())
```

but none worked

Thanks in advance